# Using operator of parent class instead of child class

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have a class called Matrix where I have parenthesis operator overloaded. I also have a child class: childMatrix (derived from Matrix) with parenthesis operator overloaded in a different way.

I have an object childMatrix, but I want to use operator of Matrix (parent class) for some calculations, is that possible?

I tried:

```
childMatrix& m;
m(1,1) = 1; // works fine
(Matrix)m(1,1) = 1 //error
(Matrix&)m(1,1) = 1 // error ( no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Matrix’ and ‘int’))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, and you're on the right track; you just mixed up operator precedence:

```
((Matrix&)m)(1,1) = 1;
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/1Ippa9)

This assumes the `operator()` is not `virtual`; if it was, you'd have to resort to rather ugly syntax:

```
m.Matrix::operator()(1,1) = 1;
```